# Regex: extract numbers between text

Tags: regex

currently I'm using such regex `"(\d{4}\b)"` in order to extract the numbers.
Test string "test 125456 b", so the extract result is "5456".

I wish to get the same result "5456" under the string "test125456b".

I tried to use following regex

```
((?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d))
```

but it works if only 4 digits (not more) are noted between letters.

So, the aim is:

- extract only digits from the text
- extract only specific number of digits In this case 4) even in the text is given more
- digits (in this case 4) should be extracted backwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\d{4}(?=[^\d]))
```

Use this. It'll look for 4 digits with a non-digit following.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tC4iC2/1)

Comment: @maraca that's what I get for doing regex in the morning I guess xD

Comment: `(?=[^\d])` equivalent to `(?=\D)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj im so glad to hear that

Comment: @maraca no, `(?=[^\d])` won't match the end of the line boundary but `(?!\d)` match the end of the line boundary.

Comment: Could we move this discussion to chat or something? I really dont like my phone blowing up with notifications on the technicalities of using one capture group over another at work

Answer (score 1):

To get the last four digits.

```
\d{4}(?=\D*$)
```

- `\d{4}` match the four digit character.
- `(?=\D*$)` Only if the four digits are followed by a zero or more non-digit characters and the end of the line boundary.
- So this matches the last 4 digits.

Comment: The OP, and future readers stumbling across this answer, might learn more if you could add some text explaining why this works.